# How to configure play application with Akka to run in a cluster

Tags: playframework, akka, akka-cluster

I have a PlayFramework (play-scala) application that I want to run in a cluster. So I might have several docker containers of this application image running. I don't know the IP addresses of these ahead of time, as the cloud services provider can start and stop them dynamically,so I cannot specify seed nodes. Also, all of the `application.conf` files should be the same fore each instance of the application?

How do I configure the play application to enable each instance of the application to discover and join the Akka cluster?

I have looked at:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaAkka#Akka-Cluster
[Akka cluster setup with play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995437/akka-cluster-setup-with-play-framework)
https://github.com/lregnier/play-akka-cluster-aws

Do I have to use [Akka Cluster Bootstrap](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/bootstrap/index.html) since I cannot specify seed nodes?

Is it enough to have the following in the `application.conf` file (taken from [Cluster Usage](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html):

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

    # auto downing is NOT safe for production deployments.
    # you may want to use it during development, read more about it in the docs.
    #
    # auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }
}
```

But without the seed nodes? If so, how do node discover and join the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the requirement, the best option might be to use [`Akka Cluster Bootstrap`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/bootstrap/index.html).  To run container-based services, `service discovery` using AWS [`ECS`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/discovery/aws.html#discovery-method-aws-api-ecs-discovery) or [`Kubernetes`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/bootstrap/recipes.html#running-akka-cluster-in-kubernetes) is probably closer to your need.

`Akka Cluster Bootstrap` addresses your need of not having pre-assigned seed nodes by means of an automatic cluster bootstrap mechanism.  Each of the nodes probes each others through their exposed HTTP endpoints and if no `seed nodes` exist (i.e. no existing cluster), the node with the "lowest" address will make itself a `seed node` prompting other nodes to join the newly formed cluster.  For more details, see this [Akka doc re: cluster bootstrap](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/bootstrap/details.html).

As described in the Akka doc, `Akka Cluster Bootstrap` depends on modules `Akka Discovery` and `Akka Management`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.lightbend.akka.management" %% "akka-management-cluster-bootstrap" % "1.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-discovery" % "2.5.21"
)
```

For `service discovery using ECS`, assign `aws-api-ecs` or `aws-api-ecs-async` (for non-blocking IO) to `akka.discovery.method` in `application.conf` which might look something like the following:

```
akka {
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = []
    seed-nodes = ${?SEED_NODES}
  }
  # ...
  management {
    cluster.bootstrap {
      contact-point-discovery {
        required-contact-point-nr = 2
        required-contact-point-nr = ${?REQUIRED_CONTACT_POINTS}
      }
    }
    # ...
  }
  discovery {
    method = aws-api-ecs-async
    aws-api-ecs-async {
      cluster = "my-ecs-cluster"
    }
  }
}
```

For `service discovery using Kubernetes`, `akka.discovery.method` should be assigned `kubernetes-api` in `application.conf` which might look like below:

```
akka {
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = []
    seed-nodes = ${?SEED_NODES}
  }
  # ...
  management {
    cluster.bootstrap {
      contact-point-discovery {
        required-contact-point-nr = 2
        required-contact-point-nr = ${?REQUIRED_CONTACT_POINTS}
      }
    }
    # ...
  }
  discovery {
    method = kubernetes-api
    kubernetes-api {
      pod-namespace = "default"
      pod-namespace = ${?K8S_NAMESPACE}
      pod-label-selector = "app=akka-cluster"
      pod-label-selector = ${?K8S_SELECTOR}
      pod-port-name = "cluster-mgmt-port"
      pod-port-name = ${?K8S_MANAGEMENT_PORT}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you include a suggested configuration to use with AWS Beanstalk?

Comment: @Shafique Jamal, unfortunately I do not have any relevant Beanstalk configuration examples at hand for sharing.  You might want to consider posting a separate question with specific requirement.  BTW, there is a nice (though a little dated) blog post [comparing Beanstalk, ECS and Kubernetes](https://fortyft.com/posts/elastic-beanstalk-vs-ecs-vs-kubernetes/) which might be of interest.